# Passport.js authentication middleware with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to make *secure routers* by using `jsonwebtoken` on Node.js server.

And I'm using `passport.js` to authenticate user with JWT.

At first, I put all logics in controller.

But all *secure routers* need to check authentication, so I tried to divide the authenticate part as a middleware

---

### Before

**user.controller.js**

```
/**
 * GET /user
 * Get user data
 */
 exports.getUser = (req, res, next) => {
   passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }, (err, payload, info) => {
     if (err) return next(err);
     if (!payload) return next(info);
 
     User.findOne({ email: payload.email }, (err, user) => {
       if (err) return next(err);
       if (!user) return next("no matching user found");
       res.status(200).send({ email: user.email });
     });
   })(req, res, next);
};
```

**app.js**

```
const userController = require('user.controller.js');
app.get('/user', userController.getUser);
```

---

### After

**passport.js**

```
/**
 * Check authentication
 */
exports.checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }, (err, payload, info) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!payload) return next(info);
    req.user = payload;
    next();
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

**user.controller.js**

```
/**
 * GET /user
 * Get user data
 */
exports.getUser = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return next("no matching user found");
    res.status(200).send({ email: user.email });
  });
};
```

**app.js**

```
const passportConfig = require('passport.js');
const userController = require('user.controller.js');
app.get('/user', passportConfig.checkAuth, userController.getUser);
```

In original `user.controller.js` I could get `email` from `payload.email`.

**BUT** after I divided the original file, I cannot access the `email` value at `user.controller.js`.

So I searched some ways how to pass data from one middleware to another, and used `req.user`.

---

### Question

1. Is this correct structure to authenticate with jwt, passport.js?

   Is this correct way to pass data between middlewares? or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good practice to use `req` to pass data from middleware to others.

By the way, you shouldn't call by yourself `next()` from passport custom callback (this is not a middleware). Passport will do  next middleware call himself in case token is valid.

```js
/**
 * Check authentication
 */
exports.checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }, (err, payload, info) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!payload) return next(new Error('wrong to'));
    //next()
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

From your `"Before"` step, there is a reason to use a custom callback because you check user email existence from it.
But from your `"After"` step, the user check logic has moved into another middleware. So you can just use passport default middleware.

```js
exports.checkAuth = passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });
```

And then `user.controller.js` will be called with the token data bind to `req.user` in case token is validated by Passport.

At this moment, you can proceed to email verification.

Comment: Thanks. But to pass the payload, I think I cannot use passport deafult middleware only. Isn't it?

Comment: Passport automatically fulfill `req.user` with unencrypted token's data in case token is valid (`If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the req.user property will be set to the authenticated user.`). You should normally have user email (into `req.user`) in case your forge the token with your email.

Answer (score 0):

Controller function is executing before middleware check, update your middleware like below using [Promisify doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

```
const util = require('util');
const authenticate = util.promisify(passport.authenticate);

exports.checkAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
    // passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }, (err, payload, info) => {
    //     if (err) return next(err);
    //     if (!payload) return next(info);
    //     req.user = payload;
    //     next();
    // })(req, res, next);

    try {
        const payload = await authenticate("jwt", { session: false });
        req.user = payload;
        //Do something
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still wonder whether this way is good or not.

Comment: @hyojoon what's the problem with this?